# How does Lifestealer's Feast work?

Tags: dota-2

How does this passive work? 
It says: " *Regenerates a portion of the attacked enemy's current HP and deals the same portion of damage per attack.* " Life Leech: 4%/5%/6%/7%

So does that mean Lifestealer heals 7% of target's current HP AND adds that 7% as damage in next attack? I can't understand this. Let's say target is Pudge with 3000hp. 7%3000 = 210. So, basically, I'm lifestealing 210hp + dealing 210 damage when attacking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, basically you got it. You will deal +x dmg, x being the % (4/5/6/7) of the current health of your target. That's why Nai'x is a scary carry (especially versus strength heroes) You just have to remember that :

- Feast deals phyiscal damage so the damage will be reduced by armor (that's why a Desolator on Nai'x is pretty cost efficient)
- The **heal** and the **+damage**  work independently. This implies that you will gain 210hp (taking your example), and the enemy will take 210 - x dmg (depending on his armor)

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that you gain the damage before armor reduction? That would surprise me if that was the case.

Comment: @Decency If the target has 1k Hp and you hase 7% feast you gain +70Damage on your attack then the total of your physical damage get reduced by the armor of your target. I Think it works like viper's nethertoxin. But i could be mistaken

Comment: @Decency: I am almost 100% sure he is correct in Dota 2. In dota 1, it was not the case though.

Comment: Any type of armor reduction will make feast do more damage. Feast does have the same mechanics for damage as nethertoxin with the only difference being nethertoxin is a set number while feast is a %. The heal lifestealer gets from feast will always be the same though, regardless of armor. I don't know exactly where the feast damage comes from, but for viper, his damage goes up before an attack based on the unit he is attack.

Comment: So actually (using my example) 210hp heal will not be reduced, the only thing reduced is the 210 damage I deal on that attack? I buy AC 99% of the time, I'm just curious if I should go for Desolator too, or rush the Abyssal. ACtually, we are talking about 210 as a bonus damage right? Let's say LS deals 190 damage, so 190+210 is the right damage I deal or not? Thanks guys. You have been helpful.

Comment: @evil yup if yuou have 190 base damage you will have 190 + 210 damage